# jQuery.ajax + php 5.3 - always executing error function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, csv

(Newb here) I have a PHP function that gets 2 csv files from the server and create a new one with the difference between values contained in those files. This PHP function is inside a separate file `test.php` and looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once('libs/parsecsv-for-php-master/parsecsv.lib.php');

$csv1name = $_POST['csv1'];  
$csv2name = $_POST['csv2'];

$data1 = 'data/'.$csv1name.'.csv';
$data2 = 'data/'.$csv2name.'.csv';

$csv1 = new parseCSV($data1);
$csv2 = new parseCSV($data2);

$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->data[0] = array('label','difference');

$j = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($csv1->data); $i++) {
        $csv->data[$i+1] = array($j.'d',$csv1->data[$i][$csv1name] - $csv2->data[$i][$csv2name]);
        if($i == 0) {$j += 20;}
        else {$j += 21;}
}

$csv->save('test.csv');
?>
```

This function *works correctly* and produces the expected csv file.
I have a JavaScript function that sits on another page (namely `update.html`) and calls the aforementioned php function via ajax:

```
    function callPHP() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"test.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{csv1: '02-01-2015', csv2: '02-12-2014'},
            error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
                alert(error);
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
        });         
    }
```

**PROBLEM**: The error function is **always** executed, that is, whenever I run callPHP() I get two alerts.

QUESTION: Why is it error always being called?

(Extra: Is it possible to work with the `response` variable? How can I debug it without having to upload my files to a server every time? Is it guaranteed that when the `complete` function is called, the `$csv->data` function was already resolved?)

Thanks for helping!!! :D

**UPDATE 1:** I changed the code above by removing the `complete` function from ajax and I added some extra parameters to the `error` function.

Comment: when the alerts are fired what is `response` ?

Comment: put a breakpoint at the alert and look at the callstack.  that may shed some light.

Comment: I think `complete` is always called no matter what I think you are looking for `success`

Comment: Your php script does not returns a JSON

Comment: @cmorrissey I added some parameters to the error function and removed the complete function. I got some extra information when I ran it: `alert(error)` gave `parseerror` and `alert(errorThrown)` displayed `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. I am guessing that ajax is implicitly trying to parse the page and is finding an error, but I have no clue on what it might be.

Comment: You are not returning `JSON` data that's why error is getting called, you can use `echo json_encode($some_data);` at the end of your script to pass back `JSON`

Comment: @cmorrissey Ok, I added `$response = array('error'=>'none');echo json_enconde($response);` and instead of getting the `parseerror` I got `error` and `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: your function is spelled wrong, and you need to echo it out

Comment: @cmorrissey I corrected it to `$response = array('error'=>'none');echo json_encode($response);` and I got the first error back (`parseerror`,`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`). =( Any idea on how to check line 1 column 1?

Answer (score 0):

complete is always called no matter its success or error. So you are running into error condition and complete gets called anyway after error is executed. You can add additional params (jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown) in error function to figure out what the error is.

Comment: I added some parameters to the error function and removed the complete function. I got some extra information when I ran it: alert(error) gave parseerror and alert(errorThrown) displayed SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. I am guessing that ajax is implicitly trying to parse the page and is finding an error, but I have no clue on what it might be.

Comment: Since you mentioned dataType as Json, it tried to parse the data coming back. you need to find out if your response is a valid json response. it seems to throws error on line 1/column1. that is where you need to look in your response.

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupidity but I have no idea on how to do that. Can you give me a tip?

Comment: You can use firebug net pannel to see the response coming back. Check to make sure you are getting a 200 success response for your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `success` instead of `complete`, and add a JSON answer to your PHP script for example `echo json_encode((object) array('success'=>true));` because your AJAX call has `dataType:"json"` parameter for a JSON response, so your AJAX call will try to parse a JSON.

PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode((object) array('success'=>true));
```

AJAX:

```
function callPHP() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"test.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{csv1: '02-01-2015', csv2: '02-12-2014'},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
    });         
}
```

Comment: I've tried using your example in the code, but I still get the error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. Any idea on how to check what is at line 1 column 1?

Comment: Use header('Content-Type: application/json'); in your php file